# asp.net error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime/Boolean'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to load to my Model the rows from the DB, I've seen a tutorial but I'm getting an error at convert type 
Here is my Model Code:

```
public class Question
{
    public Question() {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
public ActionResult Questions()
{
    String connectionString = "Password=********;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=PoolMananger;Data Source=.;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

    var model = new List<Question>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            var Question = new Question();
            Question.Text = (rdr["Text"] as string);
            Question.StartDate = rdr["StartDate"];
            Question.EndDate = rdr["EndDate"];
            Question.Active = rdr["Active"];

        model.Add(Question);
        }

    }

    return View(model);
}
}
```

I am also getting an error on "`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);`" the error is in the "`conn`". also on the "`return View(model)`;

Comment: When you get "errors" it is very helpful to include details in your question: what is the exact error and on what line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to cast them(returned from the server) before assigning them to the class variables. Try this.

```
Question.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["StartDate"]);
Question.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["EndDate"]);
Question.Active = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Active"]);
```

Please note that this will not check for any null values and assumed that you don't return with null values from the server.

Comment: If the database has the correct types, then please cast directly. Do not convert to string (`.ToString()`) only to `.Parse()` it immediately after.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
```

At this moment your `conn` doesn't exist yet. So move this line within the `using` that defines it.

I assume that the other error is at

```
Question.StartDate = rdr["StartDate"];
```

Add a cast to the correct type:

```
Question.StartDate = (DateTime) rdr["StartDate"];
```

(and of course do something similar with the other lines)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed couple of issues in your code.

1. You need to create command object after connection object available
2. Reader returns of type Object. you need to type cast properly based on types defined on database. i updated your code correctly. try below. hopefully this helps

public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List();
    }

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public Boolean Active { get; set; }

public ActionResult Questions()
{
    String connectionString =
        "Password=********;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=PoolMananger;Data Source=.;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions";


    var model = new List<Question>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            var Question = new Question();
            Question.Text = rdr["Text"].ToString();
            Question.StartDate = (DateTime) rdr["StartDate"];
            Question.EndDate = (DateTime) rdr["EndDate"];
            Question.Active = (Booolean) rdr["Active"];

            model.Add(Question);
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
}
```